# Find all continuous functions on [0,1] that satisfy $\int_0^x f(t)dt=\int_x^1 f(t)dt$ for all x on the interval (0,1)

Tags: calculus, analysis

My work:

From what I can tell, the statement is only true if $f(t)$ is equal to some constant $C$ or zero. Graphically, this is true because the area under the graph must be equal on one side of $x$ versus the other, for any arbitrary $x$. Thus, if there is any slope of the function that is not equal to zero, the integral will be greater on one side of $x$ than the other.

My question is: Is there any other instance in which the above statement would be true? Also, is there a mathematical way to describe my solution in a proof format?

Comment: Actually, I see a flaw in my logic, and I am now uncertain of its validity

Comment: Differentiate both side wrt $x$ to get $f(x)=-f(x)$. Hence $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Hint : if $f$ is continuous on $[ 0 , 1 ]$, it has an antiderivate on $[ 0 , 1 ]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous, the fundamental theorem of calculus grants that there exists an antiderivative $F$ of $f$ such that $F'(t)=f(t)dt$

$$\int_0^x f(t)dt=F(x)-F(0)$$
$$\int_x^1f(t)dt=F(1)-F(x)$$
$$\implies F(x)-F(0)=F(1)-F(x)$$
$$\implies F(x)=\frac{F(1)+F(0)}{2}$$

Differentiating on both sides leads to

$$\color{red}{f(x)\equiv 0}$$

because the $\bf{RHS}$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Summing both sides with an integral we have
$$\int_0^x f(t) \ dt + \int_{x}^1 f(t) \ dt = \int_x^1 f(t) \ dt + \int_x^1 f(t) \ dt \iff \int_0^1 f(t) \ dt = 2 \int_x^1 f(t) \ dt$$
Thus
$$ \int_x^1 f(t) \ dt = C \in \mathbb{R}$$
Rewriting with the integral function
$$ F(1) - F(x) = C \iff F(x) = D \in \mathbb{R}$$
the derivative of a constant is $0$ so
$$ F'(x) = f(x) = 0$$